# ASP. NET 5 Web API and Appharbor

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core, appharbor

I generated a new .NET Web application using .Net 5 and the Web API 5 Preview template. After adding Entity framework, and creating a basic proof of concept, everything works fine locally.
Once I deploy on AppHarbor (via Bitbucket), I get a 404 error when accessing the controller (i.e. /api/values)

Here is my dummy Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you publish your ASP.NET 5 application through `dnu publish`, you will get a structure which is similar to following one:

[image]

You basically need to deploy this folder structure as it is to your hosting provider. Assuming they have IIS, .NET 4.5.1 and your application pool is 4.0, it should all work fine when you point your application pool to `wwwroot` folder in the above structure.

Have a look at "[How Azure Web Apps Hosts an ASP.NET 5 Application](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/how-azure-web-apps-hosts-an-asp-net-5-application)" blog post for more info about how ASP.NET 5 is being hosted under IIS.